# Email "From" field being reordered

Tags: ios, email, mobile-mail

I am looking to solve an issue with iPhone reordering words in the "From" field when I view an email. Currently, it looks fine when I see it in the "Inbox", but when I click the email itself, it reorders the words based on commas.

For example:

```
University Example College of Architecture, Design, and the Arts
```

…becomes…

```
and the Arts, University Example
```

Is there a fix to this or is it just settings people have to change on their phones?

Comment: Does the example represent a single e-mail address or multiple addresses? Please could you append a full example such as `University Example Collage of Architecture <test@example.com>`

Comment: Check if that email address is present in Contacts. Also look at Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars, and then the options under Contacts (towards the bottom). It may have something to do with that email address being in contacts and how "names" are assigned to it. Probably "and the Arts, University Example" is assigned as a nickname or last name. Check Sort or Display Order, or Short Name and try to change these so that the issue stops.